# Foil rares in booster boxes?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it guaranteed that there is a foil rare in every booster box? I've recently finished opening a box and there was no foil rare and many duplicates. I already searched the web to see if it is guaranteed and couldn't find anything. I'm wondering if it was a printing/manufacturing error, or just bad luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is a strong statistical possibility that a foil rare can be found in a box, but it isn't assured. It is statistically possible to open a booster box and find zero premium cards, as well as zero mythic rares.

The probabilistic expectation, if you were to open an innumerable amount of booster boxes, is that there will be six premium cards per booster box, with one of those six premium cards being a rare. Further, it is expected that one foil mythic rare will be opened for every eight booster boxes.

Comment: I would like to note here that "expectation" here is referring to probabilistic expectation. On average, in the long run, you will get approximately one foil rare per box, but you shouldn't *expect* to get exactly one in every box you open.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - Agreed; wording expanded for clarity.

Comment: In fairness the contents are not truly random.  They do some collating to prevent "box mapping" but I doubt it's actually possible, within the bounds of the printing and manufacturing system used to pack the boxes, to actually open a box with zero premium cards.

Comment: @Affe - Short an exacting understanding of the printing and manufacturing system, the closest approximation I can provide is statistics. If they give one out, the sheet layout is known. The proportional representation for each card can be approximated from the overall count. Though anecdotal, the closest I've gotten is a box with a single premium card (land).